# What Plugin Do You Use to Turn WordPress based site to A Blog Aggregator

Tags: plugins, multisite, rss, feed

I mean that if I want to publish news feeds ,blog updates like [bloglines](http://bloglines.com) and [techmeme](http://techmeme.com/) . I and my users should have possibility to add RSS entries and the feeds should be published .

For now I am using [feedwordpress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) .But here it is grabbing the blog authors emails and creating the accounts on my site for them .For example If I add readandwriteweb's feed .Every time when the authors puclish a post on that site . That plugin is creating accounts for them.And this plugin allows only blog admin to add RSS entries .I wanted to allow the registered users to add RSS entries .

Does anybody implemented such aggregation functionality or created such aggregator using wordpress ? Could any one help me 
        Thanks !

Comment: Please specify required functionality or example sites, question is too general.

Answer (score 2):

http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can change the settings in feedwordpress and have only one user for all syndicated post.

that should solve your problem, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Pro Theme Design's [Accumulo](http://prothemedesign.com/news/accumulo-aggregator-theme-released/) theme for Wordpress gives you the functionality to add RSS widgets to aggregate content from feeds, inspired by Alltop & WPTopics.  A different layout organized by title, but you can see more on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Feedwwordpress is probably the best tool for the job. Unfortunately it isn't very friendly for modifying. The author's site is a bit confusing to navigate and will confound most basic wordpress users. The source code is long, convoluted, occasionally commented and sometimes a little funny. (See feedwordpress/feedwordpress-walker-category-checklist.class.php for a chuckle.)

But it works, and should work for Wordpress 2.6-3.1. It even supports rss feeds being put into custom post types (though you'll have to work though a little trial and error to get a custom field into your post type.)

It's a beast to write a modifying plugin for. Though I'd done one last year, I've spend the last day going through the source code because I was needing to write another fwp modifying plugin. I'm finally giving up and working around the problem in a different way.

As to your concern about FWP adding authors -- you know there's a setting for that, and you can set it on a per-feed basis. You can map authors to existing users rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the workflow that I have implemented in [Content Aggregator](https://code.recuweb.com/get/content-aggregator/).

Feeds are listed as a post type.

The feed items should take the author of the feed creator.

In your case I guess the post type of the feed item should be forced but you could also let the user pick from a list of post types.

Your users should have the capacity to add/modify/remove their own feed and feed items.

One of the notable strengths of Content Aggregator lies in its flexibility.

It allows you to easily customize metadata, assign terms by id to items, and even pull paginated feeds in bulk, but I don't think you need to go that far for your use case.